# Why did the Invaders have stiff pinkie fingers?

Tags: the-invaders

In the first episode of 1967-1968 sci-fi show The Invaders, some of the aliens had a small characteristic or defect that architect David Vincent used to identify them: their stiff pinky fingers. Certain aliens could not bend their little fingers. Also, it appeared that the aliens corrected this problem given that by the end of the TV show, they seem to have eliminated the fingers defect.

Out of the universe, some (like the creator of the TV series Larry Cohen) have mentioned that the extended pinky was a symbol of effeminacy, but I ask if there is a reasonable explanation in the canon about the origin of this characteristic of the aliens? Was it the product of a genetic failure while the invaders were mimicking the humans?

There is a scene in the pilot episode 'Beachhead' where David Vincent grabs the hands of one of the aliens trying to find the pinky defect, then, the alien tells:

-Fingers? We're not all like that, David. Some of us learn. We're always learning.

[image: The Invaders pilot episode Beachhead still image]

Comment: Just a guess at a reasonable explanation: if you are sort of duplicating something rather than growing it naturally, then there is bound to be some flaw in the process and one of the least noticeable thing would be a stiff pinkie, something that could be accounted for by a minor injury and only after meeting more than one alien would anyone think much about it. It allows the viewer to know something that characters in an episode do not yet know. I would not draw any further significance from it.

Comment: I'm supposing that the aliens in their natural form had two thumbs per hand, one on each side, and they hadn't fully gotten that characteristic out of their conversion. But the series doesn't say that.

Comment: Because they are very proper tea drinkers.

Comment: For reference: crooked little finger,a hidden meaning.  “The extended pinky used to be a symbol of effeminacy,” Cohen recalled.  “You know, the effete [person] holding a glass of champagne with the pinky extended?  When this show was done back in the sixties, the homosexual community was kind of a submerged, invisible community.   I thought, here are these aliens living amongst society, keeping their true identities secret, their true selves secret, and this is funny because the pinky kind of symbolizes homosexuality in some way, and nobody will get the gag, but I’ll put it in there anyway.”

Comment: http://www.classictvhistory.com/EpisodeGuides/invaders.html

Answer (score 4):

If a 4 fingered species were possessing a 5 fingered species, their brain/mind would not acknowledge that 5th finger, thus having never had a 5th finger, the usage of the same would be moot...

Comment: Is there any evidence that the aliens were naturally a four-fingered species though, or is that just a guess at a _possible_ explanation?

Comment: This seems like pure guesswork.